# Is This Dual Inductor Mode or Series Mode?

Tags: inductor

I'm speccing out another [DRQ series inductor](http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/dam/public/bussmann/Electronics/Resources/Data%20Sheets/Bus_Elx_DS_4311_DRQ_Series.pdf) for modifying the [DC1787A boost regulator](http://cds.linear.com/docs/Demo%20Board%20Manual/dc1787af.pdf) demo board.

I'm unsure whether the placement in the demo board schematic is in "dual inductor mode" or "series mode".

In general, what is the purpose of the "dual inductor mode"? Is it just a convenient package for two separate inductors?

[image: DRQ127 Schematic]

Demo board schematic
[image: DRQ127 in DC1787]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first link is unrelated.
 [DRQ-127-150R data sheet here](http://www.cooperindustries.com/content/dam/public/bussmann/Electronics/Resources/Data%20Sheets/Bus_Elx_DS_4311_DRQ_Series.pdf) - page 3 half way down.
 Nice inductor.
 Note that each of the two windings is about 30 uH inductance, giving 60 uH when they are in series, about 15 uH when paralleld, or 2 x 30 uH windings tightly magnetically coupled when DC isolated from each other.

The terms "dual inductor" and "series inductor" are just useful terms with no absolutely precise meaning and the terminology used is unimportant. How they are connects **is** important. Here they mean
 Series - two windings in DC series with magnetic coupling adding (60 uH)
 Parallel - two windings DC oarallel, 15 uH, currentrating double that of one winding.
 Dual - unconnected DC wise - 30 uH/winding wity tight coupling between windings.

Your configuratiuon is effectively the "dual inductor" mode. All this means is that in the one device there are two windings. It happens that they are magnetically coupled, which has an effect on the circuit they are used in. In the SEPIC circuit you are using the converter will operate WITHOUT the two winding sbeing magnetically coupled, and the converter is arguably not a "true" SEPIC converter when they are coupled, but having them coupled like this is very common practice and works OK as long as your control loop can handle the rather complex mess which results control wise. As the manufacturer is showing that this is how to use the two inductors it is essentially certain that the arrangement is OK.

In many (in fact most) other converter "topologies" where two windings are used, the magnetic coupling between the two inductors is absolutely essential to operation and the dual inductor arrangement is certainly **not** just two inductors in one package. The SEPIC uses capacitor coupling as its main coupling method.

Comment: you wrote: "Note that each of the two windings is about 30 uH inductance, giving 15 uH when they are in series, about 60 uH when paralleld, or 2 x 30 uH windings tightly magnetically coupled when DC isolated from each other." It's unusual for you to screw up in this way :-)

Comment: Two windings on a common core are called a transformer. When they are measured individually, they'll have an inductance H. When connected in parallel, they'll still have inductance H, but twice the current capacity. When connected in series, they'll have inductance 4*H -- all other things being equal, inductance is proportional to the number of turns squared. All of this is reflected in the datasheet if you read it carefully.